# Silex ControllerCollection not cascading __call to fellow ControllerCollection

Tags: php, symfony, routes, silex

I ran into the following issue while working with Silex, Routes and the `ControllerCollection` class this week:

Some plugins that we are working on attach themselves to Objects, adding routes to their representations in the Administration interface.  This results in route building that looks like (broken out):

```
$admin = $app['controllers_factory'];
$app->mount('/admin', $admin);

$user = $app['controllers_factory'];
$admin->mount('/user', $user);

$user->get('/', function() { return 'User List'; })
->bind('admin.user.list');
$user->get('/new', function() { return 'New User'; })
->bind('admin.user.new');

$user_detail  = $app['controllers_factory'];
$user->mount('/{id}', $user_detail);
$user->assert('id', '\d+');

$user_detail->get('/', function($id) {
    return "User: $id ";
})
->bind('admin.user.detail');

$user_extension = $app['controllers_factory'];
$user_detail->mount('/extension/{extension_name}', $user_extension);

$user_extension->get('/', function($id, $extension_name) {
    return "User: $id\nExtension: $extension_name";
})
->bind('admin.user.extension.view');
```

The issue I am running in to is that, while calling `$app['url_generator']->generate('admin.user.edit', array('id' => 's2'));` will fail the assert for the User ID (`\d+`), calling `$app['url_generator']->generate('admin.user.extension.view', array('id' => 's2', 'extension_name' => 'something'));` will not.  The same can be said for accessing their URLs respectively: `/admin/user/s2` (fail) and `/admin/user/s2/extension/something/` (succeed).

The same behavior is exhibited with `before`, `after`, `value`, `convert` and the `require`[http/s] methods as well.  Is this expected behavior?  The value is transferred just fine from the first mount to the Extension View, and the generator handles it swimmingly, but the `assert` does not behave as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the ControllerCollection's implementation of `__call()`. The ControllerCollection first checks if it supports the method:

```
    if (!method_exists($this->defaultRoute, $method)) {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException(sprintf('Method "%s::%s" does not exist.', get_class($this->defaultRoute), $method));
    }
```

And then it cascades the calls to it's Controllers (it is a Collection of Controllers, afterall):

```
    foreach ($this->controllers as $controller) {
        if ($controller instanceof Controller) {
            call_user_func_array(array($controller, $method), $arguments);
        }
    }
```

The issue lies in the `instanceof` check, which does not account for additional instances of `ControllerCollection`.  This has little to no static on the web, so I assume it is either expected behavior, or is not standard procedure for many people.

The fix is as simple as adding `|| $controller instanceof ControllerCollection` to the `if` condition, and I have two solutions available for anyone else expecting this behavior:

[Silex Repo Pull Request](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/pull/1100)

[Extended Class for Silex Controller Collection](https://github.com/BigRoomStudios/php-silex_controllercollection_call_cascade-class)

Either/Or.  We'll see.